# How to make a countdown timer in react native?

Tags: react-native, timer, countdown

I have to make a countdown timer in an react-native app but i dont know how, i already looked it up and and found some librarys such as react-native-countdown component but it didnt worked as id like, and got some other solutions like setInterval but i dont know how to implement it in my code and make it display on the screen as in the images below:

[image]

[image]

The time goes from 00:00 to 60:00 (MM:SS) as the user slides the bar, that changes the number 05:00 by 05:00, ive already done that but with a static number, i couldnt make it countdown.

Heres how my code is looking right now:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Dimensions, TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, View } from 'react-native';
import Slider from '@react-native-community/slider';
import CountDown from 'react-native-countdown-component';

import abacatezinImg from '../assets/abacatezinin.png';
import botaoStop from '../assets/botaoStop.png';
import botaoPlay from '../assets/botaoPlay.png';



export function Timer(){
    const [range, setRange] = useState('0');
    const [sliding, setSliding] = useState('Inactive');
    const [isSecureEntry,setIsSecureEntry]=useState(true);
    const navigation = useNavigation<any>();
    
    function handleQuit(){
        navigation.navigate('Quit');
    }
    if(isSecureEntry){
    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.texto}>{range}</Text>
        <View style={styles.container2}>
            
            <Slider 
            style={styles.slider}
            minimumValue={0}
            maximumValue={60}
            minimumTrackTintColor='#7E9F70'
            maximumTrackTintColor='#A7C99A'
            thumbImage={abacatezinImg}
            value={30}
            onValueChange={value => setRange(parseInt(value) + ':00')}
            onSlidingStart={() => setSliding('Sliding')}
            onSlidingComplete={() => setSliding('Inactive')}
            step={5}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{
                setIsSecureEntry((prev)=> !prev)
            }}>
                    <Image source={botaoPlay} style={styles.bPlay}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        </SafeAreaView>
    );
        }
        else{
            return(
                <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.texto}>{range}</Text>
                <View style={styles.container3}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleQuit}>
                            <Image source={botaoStop} style={styles.bStop}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
        
                </SafeAreaView>
            );
        }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },
    container2:{
        backgroundColor: '#E4F0E2',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderRadius: 100,
        width: 327,
        height: 66,
        paddingHorizontal: 19,
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    container3:{
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent:'space-between',
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    slider:{
        width: 209,
        height: 50,
        transform: [{scaleY: 4}]
    },
    bPlay:{
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
    },
    bStop:{
        width: 66,
        height: 66,
    },
    texto:{
        fontWeight: '300',
        fontSize: 58,
        lineHeight: 87,
        letterSpacing: 0.03,
        color: '#1B3810',
    },
})
```

If anyone has any idea how to make it Id appreciate the help

Comment: Hey @Lucca did you try this module
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-countdown-component

Comment: I did yes but id didnt work well for me

Answer (score 1):

Hooks(using useEffect) to countdown using setInterval in react - native:

```
const [timerCount, setTimer] = useState(60)

useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTimer(lastTimerCount => {
            if (lastTimerCount == 0) {
                //your redirection to Quit screen
            } else {
                lastTimerCount <= 1 && clearInterval(interval)
                return lastTimerCount - 1
            }
        })
    }, 1000) //each count lasts for a second
    //cleanup the interval on complete
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, []);
```

use the state variable timerCount as:

`<Text>{timerCount}</Text>`

Comment: It works fine but it only countdown from 60, or im i missing something? I needed it to countdown from the number the user picks from the range. But thank you anyway i will try to work that out from there!

Comment: you can assign user time to timer count and it will work accordingly

Comment: it would be assigned in the useState?